# Should the off-topic #5 be updated with a better definition of an off-site resource?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I'm looking at the #5 *rule* under [Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

- Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I'm finding [more](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23384744/3) and [more questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947776/cdn-hosted-copy-of-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-js-version-3-1-2#comment35843435_22947776) that in my opinion are more pointed towards creating a repository (*What/Where*) of information (Q1: *Would anyone happen to have that information handy?*, Q2: *I am able to find CDN's for my bundling and minification configuration for all these files except one: jquery.unobtrusive.ajax.js.*) and less about answering a specific question about *How* to solve a code/tool problem.

I repeatedly find people that feel a question is valid because the answer isn't opinionated nor spam. Based on the number of questions I see related to looking for *resources* I think the phrasing should be updated.  Should it be updated and if so what would that look like?

Comment: The first question you linked isn't a resource request; it is simply Too Broad.  The "as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam" is an attempt at explaining why we don't allow these questions; it's not a rationale for reopening them.  The only possible remedy is to remove the wording, since someone will always argue with you about that, no matter what rationale you put there.

Comment: Did you read the original question I linked, or the question after it had been updated?

Comment: I went back and looked at the edit history.  The original question is not materially different, other than it makes me understand why the original close reason was chosen.

Comment: Whether we agree or not on a single question, could a change help users better understand that looking for *reference material* (say instead of *resources*) help decrease these questions (and possibly close them faster)?

Comment: They'll still argue with you about the "opinionated" part.